# Hiding and revealing Li's

Tags: jquery

I was creating a simple accordion menu based on concept used in here
http://jsfiddle.net/WMfsR/

Basically in above example when a Li is clicked any other Li which is opened is closed.
But i want the Li's in opened state unless it is clicked again by the user..

How can this be done ?

Comment: Did you even try something? I'm really not sure if I should stimulate this sort of 'gimmethecodes', but as it seems ot be just removing 1 statement, here you go. Please try some stuff the next time yourself? please? http://jsfiddle.net/WMfsR/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WMfsR/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li').on('click',function(event) {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle(500)
    });
});​

//or short-hand ready

$(function(){
    $('#nav li').on('click',function(event) {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle(500)
    });
});​
```

you might wanna hide the children first.

Comment: is there a difference b/w `$(document).ready(function(){});` and just `$(function(){});`?

Comment: nope, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Removed some code. Updated code is here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EN5p6/1/)

Comment: hey codrin .. if i click on heading1 it shows the <li> elements under heading1.
When heading1 is in opened state and if i click on heading2 the elements of heading1 is hidden .. i don't want that to happen..
and i want both the headings to be visible

Comment: silly me, pasted your initial link. here's the version I was reffering to. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EN5p6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    $heading = $(this);
    $expandedSiblings = $heading.siblings().find('ul:visible');

    if ($expandedSiblings.size() > 0) {
        $expandedSiblings.slideUp(300, function () {
            $heading.find('ul').slideDown(300);
        });
    } else {
        $heading.find('ul').slideToggle(300);
```

to

```
    $heading = $(this);
    $heading.find('ul').slideToggle(300);
```